# Evaluating a certain definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am having trouble integrating

$\qquad f(x) = 1/(a + b\cos(x))^n,$

where $a$ and $b$ are real, $a > b$, $n$ is an integer bigger than zero and $x$ is the variable that must be integrated.

The limit goes from $k$ to $2\pi-k$, where $k$ is also real. I am creating assumptions to specify all the previous characteristics but it still does not work properly.  Does anyone know what else I should do?

Comment: [Some interesting reading.](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/)

Comment: `f[x_] = Integrate[1/(a + b*Cos[x])^n, x] ` and then `(f[2*Pi - k] - f[k]) // FullSimplify`

Comment: This should work out of the box. If I type `Integrate[1/(a + b Cos[x])^n, {x, k, 2 \[Pi] - k}, 
 Assumptions -> {{a, b} \[Element] Reals, a > b, 
   n \[Element] Integers, n > 0}]` Mathematica just solves it.

Comment: @mszynisz I tried this one but there is a problem with the generated answer. When I replace "n" for any positive value, for example 2, I got a "ComplexInfinity" in return. I do not know if the problem is about "n" or it is the integrated function itself.

Comment: @MMM I also tried this one but it gives a different answer from a definite integral solution. I have the results for n=1 and n=2, so I can compare, and the Wolfram Documentation says that substituting limits into an indefinite integral may not give the correct result for a definite integral.

Comment: @SFaria You're right, it must be a bug. It seems however that you can input the value of `n` before integrating and it works correctly: `Integrate[1/(a + b Cos[x])^n /. n -> 1, {x, k, 2 \[Pi] - k}, Assumptions -> {{a, b} \[Element] Reals, a > b}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, the solution of Mathematica is not good because of the "ComplexInfinity".
You get a good solution to the Integral with the Rule-bases-Integral-Solver of Albert Rich. See  "http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/" and install the Rubi-Programm.
You get:

```
    In[37]:= rintx[x_, a_, b_, n_] = Int[1/(a + b Cos[x])^n, x]

 (*  (1/Sqrt[1 + Cos[x]])Sqrt[2]
 AppellF1[1/2, 1/2, n, 3/2, 1/2 (1 - Cos[x]), (b (1 - Cos[x]))/(
 a + b)] (a + b Cos[x])^-n ((a + b Cos[x])/(a + b))^n Sin[x]  *)
```

As you can check by differentiating, this form of solution is right and 
it simplifies to algebraic functions with given n:

```
 In[80]:= rintx[x, a, b, 2] // FullSimplify
(* -(((
  2 a Sqrt[-a + b]
     ArcTanh[(Sqrt[-a + b] Tan[x/2])/Sqrt[a + b]])/(a + b)^(
  3/2) + ((a - b) b Sin[x])/((a + b) (a + b Cos[x])))/(a - b)^2)   *)
```

Looking at the graph with

```
  Manipulate[
  Plot[rintx[x, a, b, n], {x, -7, 12}, 
  Ticks -> {Pi/2 Range[-10, 10], Automatic}, 
   PlotRange -> All], {{a, 3}, -3, 3}, {{b, 2}, -10, 10}, {n, 
   Range[5]}]
```

you see some branch-cuts at m*2*Pi+Pi

When ebvaluating the definite integral from k to 2*Pi-k,
you have to add the steps at the brach-cuts.
For simplicity here I consider only the one at Pi.

```
  In[88]:= stepPi[a_, b_, 
   n_] = -Limit[rintx[x, a, b, n], x -> Pi, Direction -> -1] + 
     Limit[rintx[x, a, b, n], x -> Pi, Direction -> 1]
 (*   2 (a - b)^-n ((a - b)/(a + b))^n \[Pi] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2,
    n, 1, (2 b)/(a + b)]  *)
```

The definte Integral is then

```
    In[92]:= defInt[k_, a_, b_, n_] = 
      rintx[2 Pi - k, a, b, n] + stepPi[a, b, n] - rintx[k, a, b, n] // 
     FullSimplify

 (*   2 (a - b)^-n (-1 + (2 a)/(a + b))^
   n \[Pi] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, n, 1, (2 b)/(a + b)] - (
  2 AppellF1[1/2, 1/2, n, 3/2, Sin[k/2]^2, (b - b Cos[k])/(
   a + b)] (a + b Cos[k])^-n ((a + b Cos[k])/(a + b))^n Sin[k])/Sqrt[
  Cos[k/2]^2]    *)
```

Test it with numerical values and compare it with numerical integration

```
    nint[k_, a_, b_, n_] := 
     NIntegrate[1/(a + b Cos[x])^n, {x, k, 2 Pi - k}]
```

It gives the right result

```
    In[93]:= {{seq = Sequence[1, 3, 2, 1]}, 
     buf = defInt[seq] // FullSimplify, N[buf], nint[seq]}

 (*   {{1, 3, 2, 1}, (
  2 (\[Pi] - 2 ArcTan[Tan[1/2]/Sqrt[5]]))/Sqrt[5], 2.38128, 2.38128}   *)

    In[94]:= {{seq = Sequence[1, 3, 2, 2]}, 
     buf = defInt[seq] // FullSimplify, N[buf], nint[seq]}
    (*   {{1, 3, 2, 2}, (1/(75 + 50 Cos[1]))
   Sec[1/2] (3 (\[Pi] - 2 ArcTan[Tan[1/2]/Sqrt[5]]) Sqrt[
      10 (1 + Cos[1])] (3 + 2 Cos[1]) + 
    10 (Sin[1/2] + Sin[3/2])), 1.59374, 1.59374}  *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Akku14, it was very helpfull!
I just have one more question. I need to solve another integral that uses the same bounds but has this form:
(c - bCos(x))^n/(a + bCos(x))^(n+1)
Do you think Rubi can solve this one? I tried to integrate but it just returned the integral itself.

Comment: Hello @SFaria. I tried this new integrand with general n, but didn't get a result, neither with Rubi nor with Mathematica. You can of course evaluate the indefinite integrals for all given n you need with Rubi and take care of the branch-cuts.  When calculating the definite integral at n=1 with Mathematica, I got wrong results for general k. But for known k it was right. Compare it with NIntegrate.

Comment: What if there's a jump from real to imaginary in your `rint`, i.e. take `a=0` and `b=1`? How to deal with the "step" now? @Akku14

Comment: If a=0, you have additional simple pole divergences at x=Pi/2 and x=3/2 Pi. Take them into account in NIntegrate with `nint[k_, a_, b_, n_] := 
 NIntegrate[1/(a + b Cos[x])^n, {x, k, Pi/2, 3/2 Pi, 2 Pi - k}, 
  Method -> {"PrincipalValue"}, MinRecursion -> 30, 
  MaxRecursion -> 40, AccuracyGoal -> 8] `.  It turns out that you can simply ignore the imaginary part of rintx. Test  `{{seq = Sequence[1/10, 0, 1, 3]}, buf = defInt[seq] // FullSimplify, 
 N[buf], nint[seq]} ` For even n, the integral diverges.